# Excel object is undefined

Tags: javascript, excel, office-addins, office-2013, office-js

I'm trying to develop a Office Add-In for Excel (n00b).

I have managed to do some things (creating tables and taking input and so on) when using Office.context.

But now I want to go into the different cells and all examples seems to run a method called Run on a object called Excel. (https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/excel/excel-add-ins-programming-overview.md)

However when trying to use Excel it's undefined. I am running Excel 2013. Can it be that I need to use 2016?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need JavaScript APIs that can work in Excel 2013, consult the original [JavaScript API Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/fp142185.aspx) pages.

The [APIs you're asking about](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/tree/master/excel) are only available in Office 2016 and later.

-Michael (PM for Office add-ins)

Comment: it's nonsense the API was not backported to Office 2013.

Answer (score 2):

As the article says, "Applies to: Excel 2016, Office 2016".

They have added in some new APIs recently that currently only apply to Excel & Word 2016, for Windows Desktop. And even within the more generic stuff off of Office.context there's a lot of stuff that only works on some specific platforms (e.g. only Online, or only Desktop, or not on 2013...). The 2016 desktop products have the most features available.